SyntaxError: Unexpected token '' when parsing JSON response from Facebook API
I'm integrating Facebook login into my website using the Facebook JavaScript SDK. When users click on the "Login to Facebook" button, I'm getting the following exception:
SyntaxError: Unexpected token '\', "\{"user_id"... is not valid JSON
    at String.parse (<anonymous>)
    at b (sdk.js?hash=8acbe35817b4d0360dfcebc5a49d83b8:41:1617)
    at Object.decodeObject (sdk.js?hash=8acbe35817b4d0360dfcebc5a49d83b8:84:1174)
    at Object.a [as parse] (sdk.js?hash=8acbe35817b4d0360dfcebc5a49d83b8:85:183)
    at sdk.js?hash=8acbe35817b4d0360dfcebc5a49d83b8:112:3924
    at Object._xdRecv (sdk.js?hash=8acbe35817b4d0360dfcebc5a49d83b8:152:14710)
    at sdk.js?hash=8acbe35817b4d0360dfcebc5a49d83b8:152:14123
    at s (sdk.js?hash=8acbe35817b4d0360dfcebc5a49d83b8:149:2288)
    at sdk.js?hash=8acbe35817b4d0360dfcebc5a49d83b8:149:2782

Here is the relevant part of my JavaScript code:
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
        appId      : '844769960868801',
        cookie     : true,
        xfbml      : true,
        version    : 'v20.0'
    });

    FB.AppEvents.logPageView();

    // Now that FB SDK is initialized, you can call FB.getLoginStatus
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
        statusChangeCallback(response);
    });
};

(function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) { return; }
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

function checkLoginState() {
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
        statusChangeCallback(response);
    });
}

function statusChangeCallback(response) {
    console.log('statusChangeCallback');
    console.log('Response:', response);

    if (response.status === 'connected') {
        $('.fb-login-button').hide();
        const src = $('.fb-login-button').data('src');
        if (src == '') return false;

        FB.api('/me?fields=id,name,email,picture.type(large),hometown', function(response) {
            console.log("FB API Response:", response);

            // Ensure the response is a valid object
            if (typeof response !== 'object') {
                console.error("Invalid response format:", response);
                return;
            }

            // Convert response to JSON string and log it
            try {
                var jsonResponse = JSON.stringify(response);
                console.log("JSON Stringified Response:", jsonResponse);
            } catch (e) {
                console.error("Error stringifying response:", e);
                return;
            }

            // Ensure JSON string is valid
            try {
                JSON.parse(jsonResponse);
            } catch (e) {
                console.error("Invalid JSON string:", e);
                return;
            }
        });
    } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
        console.log('User is logged into Facebook but not authorized the app.');
        FB.login(function(response) {
            if (response.authResponse) {
                statusChangeCallback(response);
            } else {
                console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
            }
        }, { scope: 'public_profile,email' });
    } else {
        console.log('User is not logged into Facebook.');
        FB.login(function(response) {
            if (response.authResponse) {
                statusChangeCallback(response);
            } else {
                console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
            }
        }, { scope: 'public_profile,email' });
    }
}

I've ensured that the response is logged before parsing, but I'm still encountering this error. Could someone please help me understand why this error is occurring and how to fix it?
Additional Details:
The error seems to point to an invalid JSON format in the response.
I've checked for any unexpected escape characters but couldn't find any obvious issues.
Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

is "\{"user_id"... the beginning of the response? It seems that Unexpected token '' is pointing to the leading "" as invalid...

When i click on login to facebook button i got this error in console

Yes, as you said before, but a leading "" makes the remaining JSON invalid.

How i can fix this issue ?

Remove the backslash from the text before you parse it.

How i can remove it as it appear in fb sdk

Which is likely returned as a string, so you would use Javascript string functions to remove it.

can you please point out where should i use it ?

Your error occurs at String.parse, so you probably want to fix it before you call JSON.parse().

The response passed to the callback function should be an object already. According to the error message, the problem appears to occur in the SDK's own code, so this is probably a problem only Facebook can fix.
